# Unable to use PyDIP Module

Tags: python, c++, cmake, installation, diplib

I am trying to install PyDIP for quantitative image analysis. From the source code available online (https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib), I built the library using CMake and a Visual Studio 15 2017 generator. I ran the resulting install files generated on Visual studio and got the following output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>-- Install configuration: "Debug"
1>-- Installing: C:/Users/Deepak.Surendran/Anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.0-hea74fb7_0/Lib/site-packages/PyDIP/PyDIP_bin.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
1>-- Installing: C:/Users/Deepak.Surendran/Anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.0-hea74fb7_0/Lib/site-packages/PyDIP/PyDIP_py.py
1>-- Installing: C:/Users/Deepak.Surendran/Anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.0-hea74fb7_0/Lib/site-packages/PyDIP/__init__.py
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I can see three installed files `__init__.py`, `PyDIP_bin.cp37-win_amd64`, `PyDIP_py` at the  ...Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.7.0-hea74fb7_0\Lib\site-packages\PyDIP file location.

However when I try to import the library in python, I get a module not found error. 
I have also tried to modify the path environment variable to add "C:\Program Files\DipLib\lib" to the Python environment.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you show the error? And are you sure you pick up the proper location for your packages?

Comment: This issue was solved here: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/issues/16